# How to make PyQt window state to maximised in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4, maximize

I am using PyQt4 for GUI in my application.

I want to know how can make my window maximized by default.

I goggled but did not found an alternate.

I tried using below code, but its not for maximized instead it resizes the window to desktop screen size.

But i need the effect which we will see when we press the maximize button wt right side of the window title bar.

```
screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
self.setGeometry(0, 0, screen.width(), screen.height())
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

From [the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showMaximized):

```
self.showMaximized()
```

Comment: sorry for the delay,
even figured out another method `self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)` this is also working.

Answer (score 12):

In case you want fullscreen, you have to use:

```
self.showFullScreen()
```

Comment: This is not the question. This user want to maximize the window. Not fullscreen.

Answer (score 5):

based on the above given statement you can use this to switch beween states using the F11 Key (and exit on Esc Key)

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):  
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F11:
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.showMaximized()
```

Comment: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#maximized-prop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#maximized-prop)