# PyQt GUI size on high resolution screens

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546580/tkinter-gui-size-on-high-resolution-screens/38546859#38546859) a while ago asking about Tkinter backends and subsequently forgot about it but I've since realised that I'm using the pyqt backend. Is there a fix for that?

Original Question:

So it appears that matplotlib gui plots (a la plt.show()) don't adapt to monitor resolution and appear tiny on high resolution screens. Is there a matplotlib+Pyqt fix or do I have fiddle around somewhere in Windows settings?

Thanks

[image: Example]

Answer (score 19):

Before app is loaded, and not while loading.

insert:

```
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
```

like so :

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)


class MyWindow(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
```

And if that still don't work, in user en var and not system en var.

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=2
```

[qt-5/highdpi](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)

Comment: In case I start my app on a high DPI screen the solution works fine. In case I start the app on a low DPI screen the app window size is bigger and resized to the correct size after the application window has been moved with the mouse only. How ca I fix this?

Comment: ... I had the minimumSize and maximumSize for width and height set to equal values to get a fiexed size app window. If I reset these properties in QtDesigner to the defaults the app windows are resized the right way. How can I prevent users from app window resizing now?

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have much experience with PyQt, upon googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726296/how-to-make-pyqt-window-state-to-maximised-in-pyqt) SO question about setting the window state of a PyQT window to maximised. The accepted answer says to use `self.showMaximized()` to do so.

Comment: That just maximises the window, not change the size of the gui elements/text etc. Now the window is just bigger

Comment: @Lucidnonsense Maybe this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406939/pyqt-getting-widgets-to-resize-automatically-in-a-qdialog

Answer (score 0):

For python this worked for me:

```
if hasattr(Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
if hasattr(Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(f"Using AA_EnableHighDpiScaling > {QApplication.testAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)}")
    print(f"Using AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps    > {QApplication.testAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)}")
    # your window here
    app.exec()
```

based on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140241/9525238