# Qt Designer - Using High Resolution. Need Low Resolution version

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I designed a rather large GUI using QT designer on a high resolution screen. I am needing a version to deploy on low resolution screens. In the post: [PyQt GUI size on high resolution screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247342/pyqt-gui-size-on-high-resolution-screens) I found a solution for converting from low resolution to high resolution by doing this:

```
# Handle high resolution displays:
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
```

However, in my case, I need the exact opposite. I need a way to handle a GUI that was designed for a high resolution screen to scale down to low resolution.

Comment: So when you tested your code on a normal resolution screen, what specific problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: The GUI is too big on a "normal" resolution screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a small program to change the ratio within the ui file that was generated by Qt Designer. There are only four tags that I changed , , , and . This got it pretty close so that now I am able to tweak it with designer. I hope this helps someone else.

```
old_file = "old.ui"
new_file = "new.ui"
#Old resolution
oldx = 3840.0 
oldy = 2160.0
#New resolution
newx = 1360.0
newy = 768.0

ratiox = newx / oldx
ratioy = newy / oldy


def find_between( s, first, last ):
    start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
    end = s.index( last, start )
    return s[start:end]    

with open(old_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "<width>" in line:
            num = float(find_between(line, "<width>", "</width>"))
            #Fix resolution
            old_size = str(int(num))
            new_size = str(int(num * ratiox))
            w = line.replace(old_size, new_size)
        elif "<height>" in line:
            num = float(find_between(line, "<height>", "</height>"))
            #Fix resolution
            old_size = str(int(num))
            new_size = str(int(num * ratioy))
            w = line.replace(old_size, new_size)
        elif "<x>" in line:
            num = float(find_between(line, "<x>", "</x>"))
            #Fix resolution
            old_size = str(int(num))
            new_size = str(int(num * ratiox))
            w = line.replace(old_size, new_size)
        elif "<y>" in line:
            num = float(find_between(line, "<y>", "</y>"))
            #Fix resolution
            old_size = str(int(num))
            new_size = str(int(num * ratioy))
            w = line.replace(old_size, new_size)
        else:
            w = line
        with open('new_file.ui', 'a') as g:
            g.write(w)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) documentation, the first attribute, `AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` should automatically scale your application for all displays. Documentation [for all attributes is found here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum).

I'm assuming you've already tried something like this, where you have a boolean flag (`highres`) for whether the application is high resolution:

```
# use AA_EnableHighDpiScaling for both high and low res app versions:
if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

if highres:
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)
else:
    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, False)
```

I'm also guessing this does not give the desired result because you made your layout on a  high res screen and it's just too big to fit. You can try some trickery with [Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

For your QMainWindow, you can set global values for all widgets. Assuming your main app is a QMainWindow and you drop this in **init** or setupUI:

```
if highres == False:
    style = '''QWidget {
                   fontsize: 6pt;
                   icon-size: 15px;
               }

               QWidget::indicator {
                   width: 10px;
                   height: 10px;
               }
            '''
    self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the solution below before I saw your post. It worked quite well.