# PyQt5 Designer - Wrong Widget dimensions when loading the .ui

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-creator

I'm just now trying to load a UI file from QTCreator but the actual displayed GUI does not match with the Creator preview.

My Code if that helps:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic

print("hello")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("vertical_garden.ui",self)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow=MainWindow()
    widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Screenshots:

[image: Creator view of Demo GUI]

[image: Actual displayed GUI]

Comment: try add  `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: Sorry didn't work... Same result

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247342/pyqt-gui-size-on-high-resolution-screens

Comment: Better, but still 2 letters missing...

Comment: @Feliz_N you are not using a [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html), right? (Hint: you should...)

Comment: Yep, you need to edit `vertical_garden.ui` and add your widgets to a layout.